# Updating a column to an integer based on a datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do a mass update on an sql table, but I don't understand the logical equivalent. What I'm wanting to do, in pseudo code, is:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = (pull down the datetime from mycolumn2. if the year of that datetime is not equal to 2013, then mycolumn = 24. if the year is 2013, then mycolumn = 24 - number of months in that datetime)
```

I'm just really not sure where to start on implementing this kind of logic in SQL. Does anyone have any tips or direction for me?

Thanks

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: @marc_s I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET mycolumn = CASE WHEN DATEPART(year, mycolumn2) = 2013 
                        THEN 24 - DATEPART(month, mycolumn2) 
                    ELSE 24 
               END
```

Adjust date syntax for RDBMS as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = CASE WHEN YEAR(mycolumn2) <> 2013 
                    THEN 24
                    WHEN YEAR(mycolumn2) = 2013 
                    THEN 24 - mycolumn
                END
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a *`Simple Case`* statment:

```
update mytable
set mycolumn = 24 - case year(mycolumn2) 
                        when 2013 then  month(mycolumn2)
                        else 0 
                    end
```